# Conditionally Exclude a DLL from an MSI Installer Based on Configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll, wix

I am able to easily exclude a DLL reference from a WPF project based on the configuration with a `.csproj` that looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'MYCONFIGURATION2'">
  <Reference Include="MYDLL">
    <HintPath>MYDLLPATH\MYDLL.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But when I create the installer using Wix, the DLL is included in the installer for all Configuration projects (ex. both MYCONFIGURATION1 and MYCONFIGURATION2). I understand that for some reason, the build includes in it's output any DLLs that it finds in the source tree. I could delete `MYDLL.dll` from the source, but then that DLL won't be included for the Configuration that requires it.

My issue is that I want to include `MYDLL.dll` in all builds that are `MYCONFIGURATION2` but want to ensure that DLL is excluded in `MYCONFIGURATION`. How do I achieve this?